# Ionic3 performance issue on device or emulator

Tags: performance, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I did every possible thing to improve my app performance on the real device but it does not make noticeable changes.I remove (click) function to (tap) and add enableProdMode to main.ts but it does not help.I install the latest version of the crosswalk to my project it only increases the size of the app and it increases the performance was very tiny.when I click on the button to open a popover, it's opening in a very slow way.simple CSS animation (like on select border animation) take very long time to run the animation.

My project description:-

Ionic version: "3.6.0",
angular: "4.1.3",

My device description

Model: Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus 3GB RAM
Operating System: Android v5.1 (Lollipop)
Processor:  Octa-core (1.5 GHz, Quad core, Cortex A53 + 1.2 GHz, Quad core, Cortex A53)

It is the maximum amount of performance that Ionic gives us or I miss something?

Comment: Not sure in your case, but when I had some issues with slow animation I switched over from jQuery to http://velocityjs.org/. jQuery was good for the minimum, but anything intense I went with VelocityJS.

Comment: Basic question, just to make sure: Did you use `ionic cordova run android --prod` to run your build?

Comment: No, when I run this command it gives an error " Please consider moving TabPage in tab.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule.ts".I used lazyloading to navigate pages.